# How to correctly read /write binary from binary files using C

Tags: c++, struct, binaryfiles, fwrite, fread

I've been studying C/C++ for a while now, and while working with binary files, I encountered a very strange error. Basically, my program crashes, and I do not know why because no exception is being raised.

So, I have some structs, declared as follows:

```
struct linkingPoint
{
    int type;
    int x,y;
    int xConnection, yConnection;
    int ndxParent;
    int lr;
};


struct RECTANGLE
{
    float left;
    float top;
    float right;
    float bottom;
};

struct CMP
{
    int type;
    char name[512];
    int x1;
    int y1;
    float R;
    bool connected;
    RECTANGLE rect;
    vector<pair<linkingPoint,linkingPoint>>linking;
};
```

CMP is an electrical component, that stores some features of the component and a vector with the links to other components. I declared it as vector, because I do not know beforehand how many linkings will be drawn from that CMP. So I have a vector of pairs of linkingPoint struct.

Now, I want to save in a binary file all the CMP structs from a vector.

Save function(write drawn components in a binary file.

```
int save_project(TABLE &table, char* path)
{
    FILE* project;
    project = fopen(path, "wb+");
    if(project == NULL)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    char header[2] = {'A', 'T'};
    fwrite(&header, sizeof(header),1,project);

    if(table.v.size()!=0)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<table.v.size(); i++)
        {
            fwrite(&table.v[i], sizeof(table.v[i]), 1, project);
        }
    }
    fclose(project);
    return 1;
}
```

Then, let us asume I want to read the components back, so I can display a past project.

```
SITUATIA_TABLEI open_project(char* path)
{
    FILE* project_file;
    TABLA table;
    COMPONENTE cmp;
    pair<linkingPoint, linkingPoint>PAIR;
    project_file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if(project_file == NULL)
    {
        tabla.ans = -1;
        return tabla;
    }
    char c1[1] = {fgetc(project_file)};
    char c2[1] = {fgetc(project_file)};
    if(c1[0]!='A'&&c2[0]!='T')
    {
        table.ans = -2;
        return table;
    }
    while(fread(&cmp,sizeof(cmp),1,project_file)!=0)
    {
        table.v.push_back(cmp);
    }

    for(int i =0; i<table.v.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<table.v[i].links.size(); j++)
        {
            tabla.p.push_back(tabla.v[i].links[j]);
        }
    }
    table.ans = 1;
    strcpy(table.path_file,path);
    strcpy(table.path_to_dir,path_for_projects_directory(1));
    fclose(project_file);
    return table;
}
```

In few words, I have a vector of components CMP, which I use in order to write the components in a binary file using `fwrite()`. However, when I read the components, if a specific CMP type, have some linkings (`linking.size() > 0`) it simply crashed with the following returned proccess: `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 11.523 s`. I guess I am doing something wrong in the declaration of CMP struct. Can anybody help me with this issue?

Thank you very much! I much appreciate your time!

Cheers, geekt

**UPDATE:**

After the answers I got (thanks to everybody), I reviewed my way of writing to binary my vector of structs, by doing the following steps:

1. I have created an intermediate structs:

```
struct BinaryCMP
{
    int type;
    char name[512];
    int x;
    int y;
    float R;
    int angle;
    bool connected;
    RECTANGLE rect;
    int size_of_linkings;
    punctLegatura linking[256];
};
```

2. I iterate through the vector of pairs and I populate the array of linkings(that has a predefined memory allocation), while creating a new BinaryCMP struct.
3. I write the BinaryCMP type struct to file by using fwrite().

For reading, I do the reverse.

PS: It is not a very proffesional approach, but there is time to improve. Thank you all for the replies!

Comment: `vector<pair<linkingPoint,linkingPoint>>linking;` is not C, that's C++.

Comment: There's no such language as "C/C++".  They are two distinct languages.

Comment: `TABLE &table` is also C++. Why did you tag this as a C question?

Comment: You can't write non-POD structures to a file with `fwrite()`. `std::vector`, `std::pair` are non-POD types.

Comment: You should stop using C idioms in C++.  If you are writing C++, don't use `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fgetc`, etc.

Comment: Changed tag to c++ as this is clearly not C

Comment: This code will not work, so forget about it.  Properly serialize types that contain non-trivial types, such as `std::vector`.  Also, it seems that so many new C++ programmers are fascinated by "binary file reading/writing" when it comes to C++.  Why is that?  There are probably thousands of questions with exactly the same issue when it comes to binary read/writes, and that is trying to write non-POD types.

Comment: Brief explanation: `write` functions write exactly what is in the object to the underlying media bit-for-bit. A `vector` is a pointer to data and some extra book-keeping variables, so when you `write` a `vector` to a file, the file contains an address and some book-keeping. It doesn't contain any of the actual data. When you load the file again later, you `read` the address back in and whatever was at that address is probably gone. And if it's not gone, the outcome can be worse because you have two `vector`s claiming to own the data at that address. Chaos ensues and both will attempt to delete

Comment: Also, if you look at the parameters being sent to `fread` and `fwrite`, there is a `sizeof()` that you're using.  Assume there are 1000 items in the vector.  Let's assume that `sizeof(vector<whatever>)` is 32 bytes.  You are then asking `fread` and `fwrite` to read and write 32 bytes of data to a file, not thousands of bytes.  So how are you going to magically read/write thousands of items into a file when you only told those routines to read/write 32 bytes?  Ergo, the `fread` and `fwrite` could never work correctly.

Comment: To serialize in/out a complex list like `vector<whatever>`, you want to `fread/fwrite` [or whatever c++ idiom is equivalent] element by element. This is what you're already doing in `save_project` in your `for` loop for `table.v`. This, of course, assumes `table.v` is an array/vector of a POD (plain old data) type, such as `int`, `double`, etc.

Comment: I am sorry. I did not want to offend anybody. I messed up things. Thank you for all of your answers.  I will revise my code. Thank you very much!

Comment: If you offended anyone, they take offence WAY too easily. Everyone here is merely offering up corrections and suggestions.

Comment: Also be aware that binary file written with one compiler on a given OS might not be usable on another one particularily when reading whole struct at once. You can have many issues like size of integer on your compiler, alignment, floating point format, big/little endian. Also you have to think how you will handle future versions of your data generally by written a version number somewhere. Unless the data is intended to be used on a small device, I would recommand to use either XML or JSON text format. In any case, using a library might be a good idea.

Comment: If you're serialising data to a binary file, you should at least have a header in the file which specifies a "structure version", number of records, expected total size, magic "signature" numbers etc.  Ideally, each record should also have a header of some description.  You could also append CRCs as well.  Basically, frame the data.  Storing raw binary data in a file is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Phil1970 Thank you so much! Indeed, the program is meant for small device, narrowed use. I used to declare the data types, like uint16_t for integers, knowing that there won't be more than 2 bytes for that integer and so on. 
Thank you again!

Comment: @Den-Jason Thanks for the idea. I was actually thinking of doing that, that's why when I serialize the data, I write  some data to the header, for security issues. I will explore more on this topic.
Thank you sir!

Comment: Also, always validate that your structure is exactly the size you think it is by using something like `static_assert(sizeof(BinaryCMP) == expected size)`. While you can update the structure, you usually have to plan for it so that you know which version is used. Storing block tag and size might also be useful to properly handled different revision of the data.